# Why doesn't Dash respect the Main Menu categories?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash

I created some launchers using the Main Menu application, and sorted them, for instance in "Games". They are well listed in the Unity Dash when I click on "All installed applications".

However they are not listed in the Dash category called "Games". Is this a bug? How do I change it?

I have version 0.2.46-0ubuntu3 of unity-place-applications.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have applications listed in the appropriate category we may edit it's [.desktop file](http://library.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en) (e.g. found in `~/.local/share/` or in `/usr/share/applications`). Replace or add the desired [category](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html) like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
Categories=Game;ArcadeGame
```

With an application update `.desktop` entry files outside your $HOME may be replaced.